# Negative Sobolev norm of non-zero mean non-periodic function on bounded space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, data-analysis

The usual formulation of $H^{-1}$ norm for a zero-mean periodic function on some domain $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}$ is as follows:

$\|f\|^2_{H^{-1}}=\sum\limits_{k\in Z, k\neq 0}\dfrac{\hat{f}^2_k}{k^2}$, where $\hat{f}_k$ is the $k$-th fourier coefficient.

Is it possible to formulate something similar for a non-zero mean non-periodic function on a bounded domain.

Comment: Yes. Replace the Fourier modes by the eigenfunctions of the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: If you do as Michael rightfully suggests, the zero-mean condition will be replaced with the vanishing-at-the-boundary condition.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy do you mean Dirichlet Laplacian problem ?

Comment: Yes. Blahblahblah blah (added because they want at least 15 characters).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro What should vanish at boundary ? The function f ? Could you explain the reasoning ?

Comment: I was simply referring to the fact that you need Dirichlet eigenfunctions, that vanish at the boundary.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't understand the solution then. Am I solving $\Delta m_i=\lambda_i m_i$ with zero BC ? Then where does $f$ come in ?Is $\hat{f}_k$ replaced by projection of $f$ on $m_k$ ?

Comment: Also, would it work is $f$ itself is non-zero at boundaries ?

Comment: On the torus $\mathbb T$, you define the spaces $H^s$ using that the exponential system $e^{i n t}$ is $L^2(\mathbb T)$-complete orthonormal. Exponentials arise as a complete system of eigenfunctions of the one-dimensional Laplacian $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$. In a non-periodic setting, you still have complete systems of Laplacian eigenfunctions, but you need to specify boundary conditions. For example, the Dirichlet Laplacian has a $L^2(\Omega)$ complete orthonormal system of eigenfunctions, so you can use these to define your Sobolev spaces.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro By Dirichlet Laplacian, you mean Laplacian with 0 at boundaries ? If yes, then how can I specify boundary conditions (that reflect the boundary conditions of my function $f$)?

Comment: Yes, that's what Dirichlet Laplacian typically means. Note that boundary conditions make no sense in this setting, as the boundary of $\Omega$ is a null set. You can only speak of boundary conditions if you have enough regularity, which leads to the theory of traces. But that's not relevant here. Notice that it was not relevant on $\mathbb T$ either. A function $f$ on $H^{-1}(\mathbb T)$ is too rough to make sense of the equation $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$.